# Xpath com Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

Tenho o seguinte XML (simplificado):

```
<produto refid="cat01" idprod="tv01">
    <marca>xxx</marca>
    <modelo>xxxx</modelo>
    <genero>xxx</genero>
</produto>
<v:utilizador iduser="U00000" comercial="12344" loja="xxxxx">
    <nome>xxxxx</nome>
    <contacto>94xxxxxx</contacto>
    <email>loja@xxxxxxx</email>
    <morada>xxxxxx</morada>
    <localidade>xxxxxx</localidade>
    <cesto>
        <encomenda refidprod="rlg04" estado="enviado"/>
        <encomenda refidprod="tv04" estado="enviado"/>
    </cesto>
</v:utilizador>
<u:utilizador iduser="U00003" comercial="" loja="">
    <nome>xxxxx</nome>
    <contacto>93xxxxxx</contacto>
    <email>xxxxxxxx</email>
    <morada>xxxxxx</morada>
    <localidade>xxxxx</localidade>
    <cesto>
        <encomenda refidprod="tlf04" estado="em processo"/>
    </cesto>
</u:utilizador>
```

E tenho de elaborar um código Python que mostra todos os produtos comprados por um determinado utilizador. Fiz o seguinte:

```
from lxml import etree

u={'u':'Utilizador'} ##Declaração do namespace

file = "marketplace.xml"
treeDoc = etree.parse(file)

nome=str(raw_input('Insira o nome: '))
print("Cesto de " + nome)

elemList = treeDoc.xpath("//produto[./@idprod=//utilizadores/u:utilizador[./nome='"+ nome +"']/cesto/encomenda/@refidprod]/marca", namespaces=u)

for elem in elemList:
    print("Item: ", elem.get("idprod"))
    nameList = elem.xpath("produto")
    print(nameList[0].tag, ": ", nameList[0].text)
```

Só que não me retorna nada. Alguém pode me dizer qual é o problema?
Outra dúvida: Como faço para que no *xpath* retorne os dois *namespaces* sem ter de fazer *querys* diferentes?

Comment: Testei aqui, e funcionou. Tive que adaptar seu exemplo, pois: 1. O utilizador U00003 não comprou a tv01, de modo que nesse exemplo não era pra retornar nada mesmo; 2. Coloquei os elementos faltantes (raiz do xml e elemento `utilizadores`). Como você declarou no seu xml o namespace `u`? Foi assim: `xmlns:u="Utilizador"`? Se o xmlns no arquivo for um e no código for outro, ele não acusa erro, mas não retorna nada. Quando a retornar dois namespaces, não tenho certeza de qual a melhor maneira, mas deve envolver um `or` ou um *union* (`|`).

Comment: P.S. O xpath funcionou, o `for` logo abaixo não. Você está selecionando a marca, e não o produto...

Comment: Sim declarei como disseste, xmlns:u='Utilizador'. Não entendi a parte do for, como faço para retornar a marca então?

Comment: A marca está sim sendo retornada, é que o `for` tenta pegar `idprod` que é um atributo de `produto` (que está logo acima da marca na hierarquia), e logo depois tenta pegar elementos `produto`, que no seu exemplo não são sub-elementos de `marca`. Quando ao problema de não retornar nada, você teria um exemplo mais completo de entrada, talvez um arquivo xml real postado no pastebin, por exemplo? Pois não consigo reproduzir seu problema, comigo seu xpath funcionou perfeitamente...

Comment: Viva, obrigado pela ajuda mas já descobri o erro, na minha declaração de xpath estava a pedir a marca quando na verdade devia pedir o idprod que fosse igual ao refidprod do cesto dos utilizadores.

elemList = treeDoc.xpath("//produto[./@idprod=//utilizadores/u:utilizador[./nome='"+ nome +"']/cesto/encomenda/@refidprod]", namespaces=u)

for elem in elemList:
    print("Item: ", elem.get("idprod"))
    nameList = elem.xpath("marca")
    print(nameList[0].tag, ": ", nameList[0].text)

assim já deu.
Obrigado na mesma

Comment: Que bom! Mas antes de encerrar a questão, me explica uma coisa: por que há dois *namespaces* `u` e `v` quando a estrutura dos seus utilizadores me parece idêntica?

Comment: Existem dois namespaces que era para diferenciar os utilizadores (u:'utilizadores') dos vendedores (v:'vendedores'). Este xml era um adaptação de um mercado online onde existia categorias, produtos e utilizadores/vendedores.

Answer (score 1):

Sei que não responde extamente sua pergunta, mas já tentou usar o xmltodict?

Link do módulo: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict

````
```python
>>> doc = xmltodict.parse("""
... <mydocument has="an attribute">
... <and>
... <many>elements</many>
... <many>more elements</many>
... </and>
... <plus a="complex">
... element as well
... </plus>
... </mydocument>
... """)
>>>
>>> doc['mydocument']['@has']
u'an attribute'
>>> doc['mydocument']['and']['many']
[u'elements', u'more elements']
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['@a']
u'complex'
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['#text']
u'element as well'
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Isso aqui pode resolver seu problema:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#dicionario de namespaces
ns_dic = {'v' : 'http://exemplo.org',
          'u' : 'http://exemplo2.org'}

tree = ET.parse('marketplace.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#usuario entra com nome
nome = "'%s'"%input() #python 2.7 use raw_input()

utilizadores = [] #declaro lista de utilizadores
#busco todos os utilizadores com o nome dado independente do namespace
for ns in ns_dic: 
    utilizadores.append(root.findall("./%s:utilizador[nome=%s]"%(ns, nome), ns_dic))

utilizadores = sum(utilizadores, []) #planifico a lista

cestos = {} #crio um dicionario do tipo {user_id : lista_de_encomendas}
for utilizador in utilizadores:
    user_id = utilizador.get('iduser')
    cesto = utilizador.findall("cesto/encomenda")
    cestos[user_id] = cesto
    for encomenda in cesto:
        print("id: %s, estado:%s"%(encomenda.get("refidprod"), encomenda.get("estado")))
```

No seu exemplo, se eu busco o primeiro utilizador, o código me retorna isso:

```
>>>
id: rlg04, estado:enviado
id: tv04, estado:enviado
>>> utilizadores
[<Element '{http://exemplo.org}utilizador' at 0x00000000035B1958>]
>>> cestos
{'U00000': [<Element 'encomenda' at 0x00000000035B1B88>, <Element 'encomenda' at 0x00000000035B1BD8>]}
```

Perceba que eu prefiro usar mais `python` do que `xpath`, pois para mim, o código fica mais claro.